# Unable to mount Images for WSA during error super block

Tags: mount

I want to build a customized WSA-Image with the Source from GitHub and can't proceed. The Steps I've done, are: Setup from Ubuntu in a fresh natively Windows-Installation, guided by MS Learn-Documentations. This Run fails unexpectedly, in Cause, that I was able to create this focused Image in an earlier Installation from Windows on the same PC. So frustrated about the Error I created a VM in Hyper-V for trying there - the same Error occurs... The Error is the following:

```
Mount images fuse.erofs 1.6-g689372cd disk: /tmp/wsa-build-imVLiUgxSO_/wsa/x64/system.img offset: 0 mountpoint: /tmp/wsa-build-imVLiUgxSO_/erofs dbglevel: 0 <E> erofs: cannot find valid erofs superblock failed to read erofs super block Build: an error has occurred, exit
```